# java Process returns exit code 35 on first iteration only

Tags: java, json, curl, process, exit-code

I am calling curl with a java Process to send json text to an API. I call this code in a loop and all the updates work, except the first one, which fails with exit code 35. I believe the error code comes from curl and is a TLS/SSL connect error.

This is the heart of the method that gets repeatedly called. Again, only the first update fails, all subsequent updates succeeed. Maybe there is some overhead with establishing the initial File or ProcessBuilder which is then in place for the subsequent calls?

```
    File f = new File("c:\\temp\\json.txt");
    String str = "{\"batch_fields\":{\"Batch Number\":\""+num+"\"}}";
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f))) { 
        writer.write(str);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder command = new StringBuilder("c:\\Program Files\\curl\\bin\\curl -H \"X-Token: "+BatchUtils.API_TOKEN_READ_WRITE+"\"");
    command.append(" -X PUT -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" ");
    command.append(" -d \"@c:\\temp\\json.txt\" ");
    command.append("https://blah/blah/batches/"+batchId+"\"");
            
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.toString().split(" "));
    Process process = processBuilder.start();
    InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
    if(is == null || is.read() == -1) {
        is = process.getErrorStream();
        sb.append(" Failed updateBatchNumber: " + is.toString());
    }
    else
        sb.append(" Updated batch number";
    
    int exitCode = process.waitFor();
    sb.append(". exit code: " + exitCode);
    process.destroy();
```

Comment: You can't process the error stream like that. For now, simplify the whole thing with `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command.toString().split(" ")).inheritIO();` and just see what gets printed. Be aware that you're not building the command correctly either. It would be best to post a working stand-alone (console) command *formatted as code in your question*

Comment: You can simplify the first lines of your code with `Files.writeString(Path.of("C:/temp/json.txt"), str);`

Comment: I'm surprised any runs work as the split on space appears to make the command try to launch `c:\\Program` not curl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try simplifying to the below first. Of course, the json creation is less than proper but I've left it as is for now. You can add in more when you get proper error output, which the following should give you:

```
        String str = "{\"batch_fields\":{\"Batch Number\":\"" + num + "\"}}";
        Files.writeString(Path.of("C:/temp/json.txt"), str);
        List<String> command = new ArrayList<>();
        command.add("c:\\Program Files\\curl\\bin\\curl");
        command.addAll(List.of("-H", "X-Token: " + BatchUtils.API_TOKEN_READ_WRITE));

        command.addAll(List.of("-X", "PUT"));
        command.addAll(List.of("-H", "Content-Type: application/json"));
        command.addAll(List.of("-d", "@c:\\temp\\json.txt"));
        command.add("https://blah/blah/batches/" + batchId);

        new ProcessBuilder(command).inheritIO().start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, g00se and DuncG. This continues to work, but intermittently. I'm marking this as the solution, however, as your suggestions will allow me to debug further.

Comment: That's a little mysterious ;) What is the actual *output*?

Comment: curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed